# leaflet highlight part of polyline

Tags: leaflet, highlight, polyline

in leaflet.js  i have polyline in openstreet map:
point1(long, lat), 2(long, lat)....pointXY(long,lat)

Is possible (and how) highlight or change color only segment from point 2 to 5, no matter how to invoke.
I try add another polyline, but with more segments its mess with more and more duplicit points.

Working sample:
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/FyUzMG9Y9NrbYrzL

i looking for turn segment between [40,10],[10,10],[10,30] red. If its possible, by index [2,3,4]

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can try `GeoJson` layer to highlight a line. Just make sure that geojson coordinates are in `LngLat` format.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 0,
  layers: [
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors',
    }),
  ],
});

var data = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: [[30, 10], [45, 45]],
      },
      properties: {
        color: 'green',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: [[10, 40], [10, 10], [30, 10]],
      },
      properties: {
        color: 'red',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: [[-45, -45], [10, 40]],
      },
      properties: {
        color: 'black',
      },
    },
  ],
};

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
      layer.setStyle({
        color: feature.properties.color,
      });
    }
  },
}).addTo(map);
```

Plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/s4Q72s7RyOLp714U?preview
Ref: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/XqzvdR

Comment: Ok, thats works. But in dynamic generation highlited segmets its to complicated (prepare every colored segmests before use, not simple (huh) from index to index make it green.
But thank you for show me possible way.